# inline tags not showing on ie using jQuery

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tags, inline, html

I am facing problem rendering the contents of inline tag span. If i use div instead of span the contents are shown.

```
for (all objects in array) {

    var A = jQuery("<img src='xyz'>")

    if(some condition) {

        var b =  jQuery("<span class='X'>");
        b.append(A);
        A = b;
    }
    A.addClass(random);
}  // for ends
```

In Ie8 n 9 the object which has condition true is not displayed. whereas it is displayed in mozilla, chrome, and safari.
any pointers will be really helpful.

Comment: Are there any CSS styles that could be affecting this?

Comment: Where is A appended to the dom?

Comment: @ben  after A.addClass(random)  I have bigArray.append(A);

Comment: @brayn:  It seems the javascript is not getting generated in IE when condition is true..  checked it using debug tool in ie.. If i copy the string generated in mozilla and paste it in IE debug tool.. i can see the element showing up on ie browser..

Comment: @Ron. I'm not sure if the debug tool will show you elements added at runtime.. I remember having issue with DebugBar before.

Comment: Something I often do in ie is add a css style like * { border:1px solid blue;} that ouline all the elements on the page, that might give you some insight on why your elements are showing up ok